# Unable to configure 'Feedback' settings for Geonetwork; sending emails

Tags: geonetwork, docker

I am just trying to configure an email server into Geonetwork ('Feedback' options in settings) so users can get self-registered and receive an email. However, it is not working so far. This is the error:

```
Sending the email to the following server failed : email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:465. Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, port: 465
```

In the Feedback options, I am using 465 as port, Use SSL marked, and without TLS.

The running container serving Geoserver, has the 465 port exposed:
[image]

Geonetwork version is: geonetwork:3.12.8-postgres.

The email server (email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com) works well inside DOCKER as I have tested it using a python script.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These db params work in Geonetwork 4.2.2 for sending emails

```
system/feedback/mailServer/ignoreSslCertificateErrors   TRUE
system/feedback/mailServer/port 465
system/feedback/mailServer/ssl  TRUE
system/feedback/mailServer/tls  FALSE
```